# Dynamic select menu / cascading drop down in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

Could someone suggest a guide/tutorial for implementing a dynamic select menu / cascading drop down in Rails using best practices? Or possibly recent Stackoverflow questions around the same topic. Possibly I'm searching the wrong terms.

I've taken a look at this railscast: [#88 Dynamic Select Menus (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=asciicast) but am not convinced using a csv file to store the options is the best way to go about this.

Everything else that I've found regarding dropdowns seems incomplete or outdated.

Comment: Where does it say anything about a csv file? He's using database models. And IMO that is the best practice for what he's describing, is what your looking for conceptually different in some way?

Comment: https://github.com/railscasts/088-dynamic-select-menus-revised/blob/master/store-after/countries.csv

Comment: That is only being used by the db/seeds to populate the database, a real app would probably have an admin interface for managing that information, or use a gem that supplies it.

Comment: Ok, was wondering about that. So instead of seeding - just do a normal crud for managing categories. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you might be interested in this RESTful Rails 4 solution: [Dynamic select boxes with Rails 4](http://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/).

Basically, the select boxes are populated from the model, the controller adds an action to pick the coherent subset of data, and the view is refreshed through an AJAX request.