# How do I select a car make and then select model according to make?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails project I have two models, Car Make & Car Model, with a 1:M relationship (i.e. one Audi has many Audi models).

In my Views page, I want a form with two input fields for car make & car model. Ideally, I will be able to input a car make (i.e. Audi) and the second input field will have a drop down menu with all the models available for the make (2016 Audi A6, 2017 Audi A7).

I've set up all the relations and in the models I have saved a foreign key of the make.

currently in _form.html.erb I have

```
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :make_id, "Make:"%><br>
   <%#= f.number_field :make_id %>
   <%= f.collection_select :make_id, Make.all, 
    :id,:makes_info, {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>
 </div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :model_id, "Model:" %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :model_id, Model.all, 
    :id,:model_info, {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're looking for are dynamic or cascading drop downs.
Please consider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904780/dynamic-select-menu-cascading-drop-down-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to truly be dynamic, you would need to use an AJAX request to update the second select after the first is picked.  You'd also need to use the `options_for_select` method inside of the `select` tag

Some more [info](https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/) to accompany what was already provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's known as [`dynamic select boxes`](https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :makes do
  get :models, on: :collection #-> url.com/makes/models
end

#app/controllers/makes_controller.rb
class MakesController < ApplicationController
  def models
    @make = Make.find(params[:make][:make_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end

#app/views/makes/models.js.erb
$select = $("select#models");
$select.empty();
<% @make.models.each do |model| %>
  $select.append($('<option>').text(<%=j model.name %>).attr('value', <%= model.id %>));
<% end %>

#views
<%= f.collection_select :make_id, Make.all, :id, :makes_info, {include_blank: 'Please Select'}, { data: { remote: true, url: make_models_path }} %>
<%= f.collection_select :model_id, Model.all, :id,:model_info, {include_blank: 'Please Select'}, { id: "models" } %>
```

Comment: I attempted your solution and got a error message saying "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." when I go to the new car page, I don't understand this error can you please help Many thanks

Comment: Can you give me context for the error? Are you running this in production (Heroku)?  The code should work

Comment: I'm using a bootstrap and when I click on add new car as soon as it redirects me I get that error

Comment: What's the Heroku URL? Can you post the log of the request where the error appears?

Comment: I read the log and found out it was a syntax error, I missed a bracket whilst copying the code, how ever I am now getting a error in the views, saying undefined local variable or method `make_models_path' for #<#<Class:0x90b2578>:0x903b5f8>

Comment: That's a routing error, if you run `heroku run rake routes` in your console, you'll be able to see what the path should be cool

Comment: what is the heroku? I've not heard of it before